# How to make an interface for API response?

Tags: typescript

I have written API on PHP which have two different answers based on `success` status.

First response:

```
{
    "success": true,
    "data": {
         "prop1": "Great, it works!"
    }
}
```

Second response:

```
{
    "success": false,
    "data": {
         "prop2": "Something wrong!"
    }
}
```

How to write the interface correctly, so that after checking success, the editor understands what kind of answer is before him?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
interface SuccessResponse {
  success: true;
  data: {
    prop1: string;
  };
}

interface ErrorResponse {
  success: false;
  data: {
    prop2: string;
  };
}

type Response = SuccessResponse | ErrorResponse;
```

This way, you can use

```
const r: Response = ...;
if (r.success) {
  console.log(r.data.prop1);
}
```

And the compiler won't let you use `r.data.prop2`.

For the other one, though, it seems you need an explicit comparison with false (probably not if you use strict null checks):

```
const r: Response = ...;
if (r.success === false) {
  console.log(r.data.prop2);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can create interface like this

```
export interface  Response {
  success : bool;
  data : Data;
}
   export class Data {
      prop1?:string;
      prop2?: string;
      GetData() {
        return prop1 || prop2;
     }
   }
```

now based on success value you can check prop1 and pro2. 
you can do like this to make it working , as you dont want to choose property

```
const prodata = prop1 || prop2;
```

Comment: No, it not what i need. If i write code: res.data.prop1 + res.data.prop2, it will not give me an compile error. Because in both interface responses i have prop1 and prop2

Comment: yeah, but not i need to chose which prop to you by myself. But what if someone else will use my interface? He will not understand what response he got.

Answer (score 0):

You can write it like this

```
interface MyResponse {
    success: boolean;
    data: MyResponseData;
}

interface MyResponseData {
    prop1?: string;
    prop2?: string;
}
```

Change the interface names to more meaningful ones as per your application. I have set `prop1` and `prop2` as optional (`?`) because your sample responses don't seem to have both as required.

Comment: In this variant i need to chose props by myself. Is there no way to create conditional interfaces ?