# How to represent variable JSON data using TypeScript conditional types?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I get JSON data from a backend (I have some control over it so it could be changed to some degree if it helps) that looks like this:

```
{
  "attributes": [
    {
      "type": "string",
      "value": "foobar"
    },
    { 
      "type": "number",
      "value": 1234
    },
    {
      "type": "annotated_string",
      "value": {
        "value": "barfoo",
        "comment": "This is a comment"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I'd like to find a TypeScript type that can represent this. I read about conditional types and they seem to match part of the problem.
The `value` depends on the type (actually the value of) the `type` field.

I came up with this:

```js
type AttributeGroup = {
  attributes: Attribute[] // <-- This requires a generic parameter
}

enum AttributeType { "string" , "number", "annotated_string"}

type Attribute<T extends AttributeType> = {
  type: T;
  value: ExtractMyParameter<T>;
}

type AnnotatedString = {
  value: string;
  comment: string;
}

type ExtractMyParameter<T> =
  T extends AttributeType.number ? number :
  T extends AttributeType.string ? string :
  T extends AttributeType.annotated_string ? AnnotatedString :
    never;

let attr: Attribute<AttributeType.string> = { // <-- Ugly to have to define it twice
  type: AttributeType.string, // <-- I don't want to do this but instead: type: "string"
  value: "1234"
}
```

[Try in Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMC4IwHYE8IF4IG8CwAUBBAERxgBOAlgEYCuYIAziUgNqHHH5FfElg0ABxCtSTSlRQBzEgBpOfUgDcYwOqKQkAZgHtdNGBRKLiAXwW9uEU1wHDNpFHQC2NEMctKVajWICMAEwAzAAstha2PN72ImJkKCi68IxQAPoS1DLytvyq6o7R3j4F8YYUero5VkokAMa6Li4gKGDxACoAFlRMED3IEA1NLW25EGYRigC6hBMEhIIiEACCYJL0jADiFLp0Qli4iuTUG8xIq+sMIGxTEAD0dxAAPAC0LxBd-RQgAI50VN9ejAINIWh4qHUIEIjDBmowKLNCIQWq4VmsTld2g5cOJJNkIHInK53J5SHU6BJGiQ5gtsRcMYwnu0ICAAB6MFBQXr02iYhwAPgORUWICQ7QA3Ip8hokABRdkUGB1MAAWTQAAUYXCPEz+ZKCDSCCKIGqAMIUsCNLFLbBFSrlJA0fSgVCI+ZG7HyyhK1UarXgHXtQWYRTMtkcrloy6Ma0gAB0zjcHggAH4IImSRAEKGWeyWpGeadY3HMlJpKmIKWZFmc+H89z0byYw44+TKS4K2aLVbsdmaigQMoPPrCKBIMdzo3Tk9C3yRCW8dJgziHs83hAAKrSYAYS0QTowIcQPdQEDaKQgPqQMAAdwhIEUIsn0ZAxar0kJq9e7wAktBdCgADkkA3qg166P+x7dL0Gx9CgEggDAUDHg4WjviYvDSqKpBBGEGFmEAA)

Is there a good way to represent my data as a type in TypeScript?
The above code doesn't work for various reasons:

- `Attribute[]` is missing a Type parameter but every element of the array might have a different Type. I guess this might be solved by a Union type somehow?
- It's ugly to have to specifically define Attribute when explicitly creating an instance (this is only for testing, so it's not that bad)

I assume there must be a better way to handle this kind of data.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/57721755/571407

Comment: The typing done by TypeScript is purely a compile-time thing. The typing can’t change based on values that won’t be present until runtime.

Comment: You might want to use https://quicktype.io - they have a great JSON to Typescript type generator that I use!

Answer (score 1):

It is worth noting that the typing doesn't strictly help unless you are creating these attribute values (which you may well be); otherwise you may be lulled into a false sense of security!

You should be able to achieve your use case with a mapped type (which in this case is just a shortcut for writing a plain union: [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/DYUwLgBAJghmMC4IwHYE8IF4IG8CwAUBBAERxgBOAlgEYCuYIAziUgNqHHH5FfElg0ABxCtSTSlRQBzEgBpOfUgDcYwOqKQkAZgHtdNGBRKLiAXwW9uEU1wHDNpFHQC2NEMctKVajWICMAEwAzAAstha2PN72ImJkKCi68IxQAPoS1DLytvyq6o7R3j4F8YYUero5VkokAMa6Li4gKGDxACoAFlRMED3IEA1NLW25EGYRigC6hBMEhIIiEACCYJL0jO0OWBAA5JlS0rsAPrvObh4nu3V0Eo27ANyEC9ur6wwgADztECAAHowUFBem9qBsQFsRMc6CgANZJADuKB2MPhuiRAD4dj9-oDgSs1mCPpCQBAAPy4RT7SQyXZIHCLEBIdpyCD5DRIA4yMxPXhnVzuCh03CM5ms9lMiDnQU8qk3O4uYU4WUEMxsdpTCD00UQVGIlDi3ySvXolAqwigSDkChIUG0D6ffkXIVY7BFHVOwW7Lxso1IIJhSxzC3gZCEpi2wn2xhsTXYWO8hooCS6uH6kk7a1MNgABimADpGYndMnICakQA1I2Z8O5gsSh5AA)

```
type AttributeType = 'string'|'number'|'custom';

type Attribute<T extends AttributeType|unknown = unknown> = T extends AttributeType ? {
  'string': {type: T, value: string};
  'number': {type: T, value: number};
  'custom': {};
}[T] : {type: unknown, value: unknown};

let attr: Attribute<'string'> = {
  type: 'string',
  value: "1234",
}

let badValue: Attribute<'number'> = {
  type: 'number',
  // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'number'.
  value: "1234",
}

let badType: Attribute<'string'> = {
  // Type '"number"' is not assignable to type '"string"'.
  type: 'number',
  value: "1234",
}
```

I also made the Attribute[] work by adding a default `unknown` type.

Comment: Thank you. To go from JSON to this I'd then use a custom deserializer that instantiates the correct types by introspecting the JSON data?